# How to bring the git remote branch references local

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

One creates a new git branch:

```
git checkout -b test
```

and pushed it to origin:

git push origin -u test

and listing all the branches now I get:

```
  master
* test
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/test
```

Now, on another machine I want execute a command to get the remote branch refs. How can I do this?

I want to have the output:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/test
```

And the command IS NOT AWARE of the name of the new branches.

I have tried: `git pull`, `git pull --all`, `git fetch`, `git fetch --all`. What else?

EDIT: I need a command that tells me:

```
* [new branch]      test       -> origin/test
```

Is this possible WITHOUT checking out a branch first? I also don't want to remove my repo and clone it again.

Comment: So you want to check out a branch that has been created, without knowing its name?

Comment: No, I want to get/list all the branches that have been created on my remote `origin`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387057

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> on another machine I want execute a command to get the remote branch refs.

You can initiate an empty repo, add an origin and do a ls-remote (as done [in the comments of your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387057/git-checkout-new-remote-branch/23387667#comment35828149_23387085)):

```sh
git init newRepo
cd newRepo
git remote add origin /url/remote/repo
git ls-remote origin
```

That allows you to see the branches of the remote repo without having to clone / fetch anything locally.
And since you are in an empty repo, you can then decide what to fetch.

---

As [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592397/how-to-bring-the-git-remote-branch-references-local/23387898#comment36010806_23387898), the [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) part doesn't need to be run from a git repo.
As an example, consider:

```sh
cd / # to illustrate that you can be anywhere
git ls-remote git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git 'refs/heads/*'
```

---

If you have already a cloned repo, and don't mind to download the delta, then a git fetch should work, provided that its refspec is set to fetch all branches.
(Again, as shown in your other question "[git checkout new remote branch when cloning with depth 1 option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23387085/6309)")

```sh
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

Comment: `git ls-remote` works from anywhere, you don't need to init a throwaway.  `( cd /; git ls-remote git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git 'refs/heads/*'; )`

Comment: @jthill True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

To list the remote branches of a local repository, in this case it's

```
$ git branch --remote |grep origin
```

In your case, to update remote refs of a repo corresponding to another remote repo called `origin`, it's

```
$ git fetch origin
```

This will create a new remote branch `origin/test` if it was created on the remote repo. You can then make it a local branch and check it out with

```
git checkout --track origin/test
```

Comment: This lists them only but it does not update the local refs. i.e. `git branch -a` does not list: `remotes/origin/test`

Comment: I want to UPDATE the refs in my local clone, not to list the remote branches

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay try `git checkout --track origin/test` it must work.

Comment: I don't know the name **test**. I want to fetch all remote branch refs.

Comment: I assume you know the name of the origin.  Then: `git for-each-ref --shell --format="git checkout --track %(refname:short)" refs/remotes/origin` (the output is commands you can feed to sh)

Comment: Nope, this only shows me the remotes that I know already (`HEAD` and `master`). `test` does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a git repo and just want to track a new branch from remote, you can use:

```
git checkout --track origin/test
```

if you want to clone a perticular branch:

```
git clone -b test <remote location>
```

Comment: I don't know the names of new branches, I want to update all the refs

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay try CharlesB answer ie `git ls-remote --heads origin`

Comment: why downvote any thing wrong? please mention it. i am using these for so long without any problem. That is how we trust some thing.