# git checkout new remote branch when cloning with depth 1 option

Tags: git, branch, git-clone, git-remote

After I did a clone of a repo, a new branch `test` has been added to the `origin` remote. But I still see:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

What git command/s should I use to get the following output:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/test
```

The [git checkout remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch) question is not my question because that is happening after I see all the remote branch references.

I cannot clone the repo again because I have my local changes/commits in it.

So, how to bring the new remote branch references to my repo using git commands?

I am using a BitBucket repo that has the following branches: [image: branches]

---

**Trials**

`git fetch` does not work:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
$ git fetch
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
$ git fetch origin 
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) should be enough.

That will bring origin/test to your repo.

Then a `git checkout -b test origin/test` will declare that branch locally.

---

The [OP Gabriel Petrovay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454103/gabriel-petrovay) confirms ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387057/git-checkout-new-remote-branch/23387085?noredirect=1#comment35828374_23387085)) the source of the problem:

> There is a slight change in the git config file.
>
> - In the newly cloned repo `[remote "origin"]` has `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
> - but the old repo has `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`.
>
> I kind of feel this is the issue.

It is indeed.

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

That should solve it.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay if you clone again that repo elsewhere (just for test), do you see `origin/test` then? (`git branch -av` in that new clone).

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay does `git remote -v` in your current repo shows the right url to the right remote repo with the test branch?

Comment: Yes I just cloned to a new location and I see them:
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/crud_links_ui
  remotes/origin/form_update
  remotes/origin/master

See the image in the post. (`test` branch was just to simplify the question)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay does `git remote -v` returns the same in the `newly cloned repo`, and in your `original repo`?

Comment: Yes they are the same: `$ git remote -v`: `origin git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git (fetch)` and
`origin git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git (push)`

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay in both local repos, what does a `git ls-remote` return?

Comment: In both I get all the branches listed with their top commit:
`HEAD`,
`refs/heads/crud_links_ui`,
`refs/heads/form_update`,
`refs/heads/master`

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay then I don't see any reason why a git fetch wouldn't... fetch.

Comment: There is a slight change in the git config file. In the newly cloned repo `[remote "origin"]` has `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` but the old repo has `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`. I kind of feel this is the issue.

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay yes, I have edited the answer with the right command.

Comment: Thanks @VonC for helping me debug this!

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay no problem, you are welcome. I prefer using `git config` command to change the config, rather than editing directly the `.gitconfig` file. Hence the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem!!!

A git clone with a depth 1:

```
git clone --depth 1 <repo>
```

will only need the master branch reference and the git repote config generated for this repo will be:

```
[remote "origin"]                                                                                                
   url = git@bitbucket.org:jillix/cctool.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

instead of:

```
[remote "origin"]                                                                                                
   url = git@bitbucket.org:jillix/cctool.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This will make the fetch fail in bringing all the remote references.